# Running rake db:drop db:create db:migrate on Heroku Cedar stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, cedar

When I try to run:

```
heroku run rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

I get the error:

```
Running rake db:drop attached to terminal... up, run.5
Couldn't drop adsfsadfas : #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  must be owner of database adsfsadfas
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "adsfsadfas">
```

I am on the Heroku Cedar stack.  Am I allowed to drop databases on Heroku?

Thanks!

John

Comment: Here is an up to date answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13347768/1417223

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> The rake db:reset task is not supported. Heroku apps do not have permission to drop and create databases. Use the `heroku pg:reset` command instead.

Comment: yeah, you need to type `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` then input your app name at the prompt when asked

Comment: this has now changed to `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm nameofapp` - ymmv

Comment: Note also with the (now deprecated) Heroku gem, `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL` will also delete your schema, despite `heroku help pg` docs indicating "Delete all data in the database". Though, in the OP's case that's what is wanted (`rake db:drop`).

Comment: Joshua Schmid pointed out that you may need to also run: heroku run rake db:schema:load

Comment: `heroku pg:reset` then `heroku run rake db:migrate` (and optionally `db:fixtures:load` as that was for my staging environment)

Answer (score 13):

Directly destructive commands (*drop* and *create*) are not permitted on heroku. But if you're ok with loosing all the data, you can reset the database with `pg:reset`.

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

Every other change should be done with `db:migrate`. This assures consistency of the database state.

---

If your migrations don't run through the full stack anymore you can use `db:schema:load`. This loads the schema directly from *schema.rb*. But be aware that this can also be destructive if `create_table` uses the parameters `force: true` or `force: :cascade`.

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```